# KeyNotFoundException with RavenDb

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ravendb, asp.net-web-api2

Just installed RavenDb Build-3528 as a Website in IIS.

RavenDb is running just fine, management studio is reachable on http://localhost:8080, created databases etc, so far no problem.

However when I start my MVC 5 application (with regular MVC Controllers and WebApi Controllers) the application crashes on startup with the json message:

```
{
    message: "An error has occurred.",
    exceptionMessage: "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",
    exceptionType: "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException",
    stackTrace: " at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.RavenBaseApiController.InnerInitialization(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\RavenBaseApiController.cs:line 101 at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.RavenDbApiController.InnerInitialization(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\RavenDbApiController.cs:line 112 at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.RavenDbApiController.<ExecuteAsync>d__3a.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\RavenDbApiController.cs:line 54 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Funny thing is: before installing RavenDb as Website in IIS we used RavenDb 2.5 as embedded server in our MVC application and worked just fine.

In the Windows Event Manager I can't find any useful information.

Anyone an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hah!

It turns out that if you comment out the following line in `WebApiConfig.cs` that error disappears:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  // <--- Offending line
```

Apparently RavenDB calls `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` as well so there's a conflict...

Of course, commenting out that line means that the WebApi routes no longer work, throwing an `Multiple actions were found that match the request` error.

### ***UPDATE***

On my solution there is a project with Unit Tests that requires `Raven.Database.dll` because it uses the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` to run tests in memory.

This `Raven.Database.dll` ends up on the `bin` folder of the MVC/WebApi project. As soon as you delete it, the website works. So it really is the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` wrecking havoc with WebApi.

In short, make sure you have no references to `Raven.Database.dll` in your WebApi projects, and that the dll doesn't end up in the `bin` of your WebApi project either (by setting `Copy to Local = false`, for instance).

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out that somehow my main project had a reference to the test project, that's why `Raven.Database.dll` ended up in my main project's bin folder. Just removing that unnecessary reference does the trick, no neet to set `Copy to Local = false`.

Comment: wow this saved me - Raven.Database.dll in the bin folder was killing me.

Comment: OK, so what if you want to use an EmbeddableDocumentStore inside a web api project...?

Comment: It turns out that it is not a supported scenario. Basically, you can't.